# showing the hidden text with a fade effect along with the background div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I applied a fade effect when clicked on a main text. but the div behind it is 
kinda rough during the effect. The hidden text appears with a fade-in effect but the div does not.

How can I make the div fade along with the text. 
heres the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/826/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
       $(this).find(".hide").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);

   .spcredit{
    color:#666666;
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:9px;
    }
.category {
width:440px;
padding-top:10px;
margin-bottom:40px;
background:white;
text-align:justify;
box-shadow:0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.15)
}
```

```html
<div class="category" style="line-height:150%;"><center>


<div class="spcredit">
<div class="toggle"><a href="javascript:void(0);">text1</a>
<div class="hide">
hidden text1
</div></div>

</div>
```

For some weird reason it does not work in the preview. Here's [FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/826/)

Comment: You need to take `.hide` element out of `.category`. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/829/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `slideToggle()` instead of `fadeToggle()`

Edit:
If you want to have both fading and sliding you need to use another wrapper for that. Edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BreMW/830/)

Comment: how do i increase the sliding speed ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `div` with class `category`. It adjusts its height to the new element so it is out of the animation.

The following creates a decent animation.

```
var hidden = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
       if (hidden) {
         $(".category").animate({
          height: '+='+ $(".category").height() + 'px'
         }, 1000);
         hidden = false;
       }
       else {
         $(".category").animate({
          height: '-='+ $(".category").height() / 2 + 'px'
         }, 1000);
         hidden = true;
       }
       $(this).find(".hide").fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedosama/aa2LLn06/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.parent()` on `$(this)` and then call `.toggle()` instead of `fadeToggle()`. You can also select the speed. See the code here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dirgepye/zzec8fLk/)